# Converse seems to be logically equivalent to conditional?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

This is part of a question (PS: the question just asked me to write converse, inverse, contrapositive counterparts. My question is not related to the question itself):

> Statement: ∀n ∈ Z, if (6 | n), then (2 | n) and (3 | n).
>
> Converse: ∀n
> ∈ Z, if (2 | n) and (3 | n), then (6 | n).

I understand that converse statements are **NOT** logically equivalent to conditional statements.

For them to be logically inequivalent, we just need one instance where predicates have opposite truth values for a particular chosen value of the predicate variable.

But I'm unable to find that one instance (counter-example) that would prove that the converse and the original are not logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your statement, the converse is true since $\mathrm{lcm}(2,3)=6$ but it isn't always.

$\forall\ n \in \mathbb{Z},$ if $12 \mid n,$ then $2 \mid n$ and $3 \mid n$ but the converse is not true.

Comment: Could you give me a counter example, ie a value of n such that one is true and other is false?

Comment: @Leon $2\mid 6$ and $3 \mid 6$ but $12\not\mid 6.$

Comment: As in a counter-example for the converse that uses  (6 | n), not  (12 | n).My bad for being vague

Comment: @Leon I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean it "uses $6 \mid n$?" How about $2\mid 18$ and $3 \mid 18$ but $12 \not\mid 18?$

Comment: As in I would like to use the statements in the question I posted because I can't find a counter-example for the ones I posted

Comment: @Leon Yes because your statement and its converse *are* logically equivalent as I indicated in my answer.

Comment: @Leon: I hope you understood this answer, but I wish to add that this kind of confusion is why it *pays greatly* to be as **precise** as possible. In particular, it is actually wrong to say "The converse of a conditional statement is not equivalent to itself.". The correct statement is "There is a conditional statement that is not equivalent to its converse.".